# Creating a function that returns a curried function (SML)

Tags: functional-programming, sml, currying, partial-application

I've written a function that calculates a value of x, of a polynomial made from a list of reals.

```
infixr 5 ^^;

fun (x:real) ^^ 0 = 1.0
  | (x:real) ^^ n = x*(x^^(n-1));

fun poly [] (x:real) = 0.0
  | poly (hd::tl) (x:real) = hd*(x^^(length tl)) + poly tl x;
```

This code all works perfectly fine, and I'm quite proud of it.

I have managed to create polynomial functions using partial application:

```
> fun f x = poly [3.0,2.0,1.0] x;
val f = fn : real -> real

> f 2.0;
val it = 17.0 : real
```

Creating the mathetmatical function:`f(x) = 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1`

This is all fine, but I want to be able to construct a function by this method:

```
fun f x = polyGen [1.0,2.0,3.0];
```

And it will give me an equivalent function to the one above. 
Is this possible?
I know it seems trivial, I could just put an x there as I did before and get on with my life. But I'm just curious on how someone would get around this problem!

Thanks in advance, Ciaran

EDIT:

```
fun polyGen L = let fun poly [] x = 0.0
                      | poly (hd::tl) x = hd + x*(poly tl x);
                in fn x => poly L x end;
```

Lovely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you don't need to define anything else at all. With the function `poly` that you have you can already do

```
val f = poly [3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

which defines `f` as a function of type `real -> real`.